# IdP status page returns "HTTP Status 404"

Tags: xml, spring, apache, tomcat, shibboleth

I am using shibboleth idp to use sso for my project, but in the configurations like idp.xml
i am using relative paths instead of absolute path(E:\SRDM2.3.0.6904.10\SRDM\Svr\IdP\IdPserver\idp)

```
<Context docBase="../../Idp/IdpServer/idp"  // relative path
         privileged="true"
         antiResourceLocking="false"
         antiJARLocking="false"
         unpackWAR="false" />
```

I have the following folders under E:\SRDM2.3.0.6904.10\SRDM\Svr
a)tomcat
b)Idp -- >Idpserver-->idp -->WEB-INF->service.xml
   Idp -- >Idpserver-->conf->attribute-resolver.xml

I have the service.xml like below

```
<srv:Service id="shibboleth.AttributeResolver" xsi:type="attribute-resolver:ShibbolethAttributeResolver">
        <srv:ConfigurationResource file="../../Idp/IdPserver/conf/attribute-resolver.xml" xsi:type="resource:FilesystemResource"/>
</srv:Service>
```

If i use the above code i am getting following error if run tomcat.
HTTP Status 404 
type Status report
message
description The requested resource is not available.
Apache Tomcat/6.0.41

Please find my below logs regarding error:
**catalina2014.log**

INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor idp.xml
Nov 12, 2014 11:51:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Nov 12, 2014 11:51:06 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext start
SEVERE: Context [/idp] startup failed due to previous errors

**localhost.log:**

SEVERE: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener 
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'shibboleth.AttributeResolver': Invocation of init method failed;
nested exception is edu.internet2.middleware.shibboleth.common.service.ServiceException: 
Configuration was not loaded for shibboleth.AttributeResolver service, error creating components.

My above log i am thinking that the path given in the service.xml
file="../../Idp/IdPserver/conf/attribute-resolver.xml" is not proper.

Please look into my above explained folder structure and give me some suggestions.
thank your for patience.

Comment: could any body please look into my above query.

Comment: I don't have an answer or citation, but I'm pretty sure relative paths aren't supported.

Comment: No Martin, relative paths are supported, I would be able to figured it out.